# Conversion from 'void *' to 'vector<int *>'

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, vector, casting

I am casting a vector pointer as a void pointer to a function. In that function, how to I cast it to a vector pointer?

```
in main

vector<int *> foo;
function(&foo);

in function
function(void *bar){
    auto temp = bar; // what replaces auto or what should bar be cast to?
    temp.pushback(something);
}
```

I hope I have not mangled the terminology, any opinion helps!

Comment: what's wrong with cast it back?

Comment: inside the function, bar is seen as a 'void *' but I want to use it as a 'vector<int *>'

Comment: So replace `auto temp = bar;` with `auto temp = static_cast<std::vector<int *> *>(bar);` (unless some other cast is needed, I haven't tested).

Comment: @mediocrevegetable1 `static_cast` will work just fine

Comment: I guess the elephant in the room is why your design has `void*` to begin with.  Given C++ type safety, what's the reason for using `void *`?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie pthread_create is why, I need to pass a vector<int *> as argument to pthread_create and the function to be called and also gets the argument...

Comment: as you tagged `c++11` you should probably switch to `std::thread`.

Comment: @user49706 -- *pthread_create is why* -- Well, as the previous comment suggests, the C ++11 `std::thread` knows the types you send, thus does not require `void *`.

Answer (score 3):

You are not casting it, but thats just an implicit conversion. The method is called `push_back` and you need `->` to dereference.

If you are absolutely certain that the `void*` points to a `vector<int*>` you can safely cast it back:

```
#include <vector>

void function(void *bar){
    auto temp = static_cast<std::vector<int*>*>(bar);
    temp->push_back(new int);
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int *> foo;
    function(&foo);
}
```

However, the question arises: Why all the pointers? If by any means you can change `function` and the vector is supposed to store integers your code should look like this:

```
#include <vector>

void function(std::vector<int>& v){
    v.push_back(42);
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> foo;
    function(foo);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can apply `static_cast`.

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

void function( void *bar )
{
    auto pv = static_cast<std::vector<int *> *>( bar );
    
    for ( const auto &p : *pv ) std::cout << *p << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';
}

int main() 
{
    int a[] = { 1, 2, 3 };
    std::vector<int *> v;
    
    for ( auto &x : a ) v.push_back( &x );
    
    function( &v );
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
1 2 3
```